# Deleting pages automatically from a PDF

Tags: pdf

My professor provides ppt slides as PDF so there a lot of redundant slides. Is there a software which can extract useful pages directly such that I do not need to remove pages manually.
[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to delete the first two images.

Comment: Not an answer to your question. The slides look like they are created by LaTeX so you could tell your teacher to create the slides with the `draft` option in the `documentclass`. This will coalesce all these 'step-by-step' slides into one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this webpage here: https://smallpdf.com/delete-pages-from-pdf to remove pages from a pdf.

Comment: Then apart from my comment above you seem out of luck. To do this after creating the pdf you would have to analyze the content of the pdf and decide whether the slide is a new one or an increment of the previous one.